# Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток. Являясь полнейшим профаном в программировании в целом я наткнулся на сайт http://strolen.com/viewing/Cryptic_Language_-_Times_Ultra-New_Roman

Меня заинтересовал данный вид написания символов, и в самом низу этой статьи есть ссылка на архив, как я понял, для написания их посредством Java-машины. После загрузки этого архива в нём я обнаружил 2 файла с расширением .java : CharacterLibrary и Main. После продолжительного воскуривания мануалов по данной прекрасной среде программирования мной была установлена Java-машина jdk, были со скрипом прописаны пути к bin, в настройках были прописаны пути PATH, и после того как я через консоль пытался компилировать командой javac файл MAIN, консоль ругается вот таким матом:

> main.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
>               Y = CharacterLibrary.drawCharacter(g, X, Y,
>                   ^   symbol:   variable CharacterLibrary   location: class Main main.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
>                   Y = CharacterLibrary.drawConnect(g,X,Y);
>                       ^   symbol:   variable CharacterLibrary   location: class Main main.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
>               Y = CharacterLibrary.drawCharacter(g, X, Y,
>                   ^   symbol:   variable CharacterLibrary   location: class Main main.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
>                   Y = CharacterLibrary.drawConnect(g,X,Y);
>                       ^   symbol:   variable CharacterLibrary   location: class Main 4 errors

Пожалуйста, объясните дебилу, как заставить работать данные файлы.

Comment: Укажи все файлы компилятору

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Похоже, у вас установлено несколько разных версий `Java` и возникла путаница с ними (разные переменные среды оказались в несогласованном состоянии). Проще всего, пожалуй, деинсталлировать их все, почистить переменные среды `path` и `classpath`, чтобы там не осталось никаких упоминаний о `java`, и установить какую-то одну версию `JDK`.
2. После установки `JDK` убедитесь, что компилятор и виртуальная машина доступны и относятся к одной версии. Для этого из консоли выполните команды `java -version` и `javac -version`. Вы должны увидеть что-то вроде `java version "1.8.0_201"` и `javac 1.8.0_201` соответственно. Кстати, советую для таких вещей использовать не стандартную виндовскую консоль, а какой-нибудь файловый менеджер типа `far`, это намного удобней, видна структура директорий и файлы.
3. Создайте какую-нибудь директорию или воспользуйтесь готовой, но чтобы не путаться, лучше, чтобы в ней не было ничего постороннего. Назовем ее условно `C:\myDir`. В ней создайте поддиректорию `alientextgenerator` и в эту поддиректорию поместите файлы с исходниками (`Main.java` и `CharacterLibrary.java`).
4. Зайдите в поддиректорию командой `cd C:\myDir\alientextgenerator` или файловым менеджером. По команде `dir` или в окне файлового менеджера вы должны видеть свои файлы. В исходной программе есть глупость, которая помешает ей работать -- она будет пытаться создать файл в несуществующей директории. Исправьте -- любым текстовым редактором откройте `Main.java`, найдите там строку

   `ImageIO.write(myImage, "gif", new File("C:\\Users\\Tim\\Desktop\\" + fileName));`

   (Это почти в самом конце) и замените ее на

   `ImageIO.write(myImage, "gif", new File(fileName));`
5. Оставаясь в той же поддиректории, откомпилируйте файлы командой `javac Main.java CharacterLibrary.java`. Должны появиться файлы `Main.class` и `CharacterLibrary.class`.
6. Выйдите из поддиректории в директорию `C:\myDir` и запустите программу комндой `java alientextgenerator/Main`. Она должна отработать и в вашей текущей директории (`C:\myDir`) записать файл `example_sentence.png` с нужными вам картинками.

Что именно вы делали не так и почему у вас не получалось, сказать трудно. Алгоритм, который я описал -- не единственный, все это можно проделать и другими способами, но мне показалось, что для новичка этот способ наиболее прост.

Эти фокусы с поддиректорий `alientextgenerator`, которые могут показаться бессмысленными, обусловлены принятым в `Java` правилом -- классы должны находиться в поддиректориях, чьи названия соответствуют названиям пакетов. В ваших фалах указан пакет -- `package alientextgenerator;`, значит файлы `*.class` должны находиться в поддиректории `.\alientextgenerator`. Если у вас в исходном файле написано `package com.my.package;`, виртуальная машина будет искать соответствующий `.class` файл в поддиректории `\com\my\package\` относительно вашей текущей директории и относительно директорий, перечисленных в переменной среды `classpath` и в ключе `-cp`, указанном при запуске `JVM` из командной строки.

А вообще надо сказать, что `jdk` в чистом виде используется крайне редко, в каких-то экзотических ситуациях. Обычно все используют `IDE`, такие как `Eclipse`, `IntelliJ IDEA` и проч. Если всё идет нормально, программист зачастую может годами не вспоминать ключи компилятора или опции виртуальной машины, но разобраться с этим хотя бы раз -- нужно. А разбираться с `JDK` и `JVM` (как и с программированием на `Java`) я бы советовал для начала не по мануалам, а по хорошим учебникам -- напр. Хорстман, "Java SE 8. Базовый курс" (Cay S. Horstmann. Core Java for the Impatient)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, руководствуясь вашим объяснением и здравым смыслом установил CLASSPATH-ом мою корневую папку с исходниками, а PATH-ом папку bin установленного jdk, после этого всё зафунциклировало :)  жаль только что приходится каждый раз для разного набора символов компилировать программу заново (да-да я сам нашёл строчки, которые надо менять в MAIN.java для написания разных фраз) за напутствие спасибо, но с "Программированием" думаю пока завязать, прекрасно что на данном сайте есть настолько высококвалифицированные специалисты. И да, спасибо ещё раз.

Answer (score 1):

Вы компилируете только один класс `Main`, но не `CharacterLibrary`

`javac -d /путь/к/папке/с/исходниками Main.java`

Comment: Ругательства приняли такие обороты, пытался запустить и один и второй файл 
C:\Users\Neveragain>javac C:\Users\Neveragain\Desktop\123 Main.java
error: invalid flag: C:\Users\Neveragain\Desktop\123
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

C:\Users\Neveragain>javac C:\Users\Neveragain\Desktop\123 CharacterLibrary.java
error: invalid flag: C:\Users\Neveragain\Desktop\123
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

Comment: -d забыли дописать

Comment: error: file not found: Main.java
Извините, я опять что-то делаю не так

Comment: там где вы запускаете javac (папка в которой находится консоль) имеется файл Main.java?

Comment: Я запускаю данную команду из консоли, которую открываю из папки где находятся оба файла, так же попробовал прописывать эти команды через запуск общей консоли (win+r, cmd)

Comment: Ну т.е. когда вы пишите команду dir в консоли видите файл, так?

Comment: Абсолютно верно, вот что мне показывает магия консоли 
18.02.2019  19:53    <DIR>          .
18.02.2019  19:53    <DIR>          ..
18.10.2015  04:57            14 997 CharacterLibrary.java
18.10.2015  05:14             3 824 Main.java
               2 файлов         18 821 байт
               2 папок  19 467 550 720 байт свободно

Comment: хорошо, тогда по тупому `javac Main.java CharacterLibrary.java`

Comment: Классы создались, при их запуске посредством консоли выдает ещё более страшную ругань 
'Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: CharacterLibrary has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0'

Comment: Я так понял это из-за различий версий Java-машины, на данный момент установлена Java 8 Update 201 и Java(TM) SE Development Kit 11.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: Потыкавшись ещё час с разными версиями jvk и jvr, шаманством с переменными средами, различными способами прописи в консоли запуска файлов я получаю на выбор 3 ошибки, либо не можем найти класс, либо версия не та, либо консоль выводит просто справку, если я пытаюсь запустить с -cp. Чувствую себя конечно олигофреном, жаль что создатели той статьи не придумали что-нибудь полегче для простого обывателя...

Comment: ну можно было бы сказать NetBeans какой-нибудь и запустить там